# How to kill all running threads in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How to kill all running threads in Silverlight?

Comment: ...are votes so important for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the `Abort` method of a `Thread` object is marked as security critical and can't be called in Silverlight code.

If you want to kill the running of your own code then you could use the `BackgroundWorker` class to run the code and place reasonable checks in the code for `CancellationPending` being set.  Other code can then call `CancelAsync` to terminate it.